# MUI data grid not reading first row

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a React app an I am using MUI data grid with some editable columns.

myRows are defined in local component state. I have a version with this state coming from Redux store, but the behavior is the same.

```
const [ myRows, setMyRows ] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      row:  1,
      accountCode: '',
      partner: '',
      amountCredit: null,
      amountDebit: null,
      accountNote: '',
      date: new Date().toISOString()
    }
  ]);
```

Namely, I need one initial empty row when I want to create a new item and that empty row is my initial state for myRows.

The problem comes when i click on an existing item to edit it, and set its rows to be myRows state.
For some reason the first row is not being read, some elements of that row. Rows state is correctly set, but not read by grid.

The problem is definitely in this empty row that sits as initial state. I know this because I tried to hardcode the elements in that initial row and they are displayed correctly.

Comment: Please provide a code sandbox that reproduces your problem and include in your question the full code needed to reproduce it.